# Not an answer flag declined because post was edited 2 days afterwards

Tags: discussion, edits, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156413/communication-between-gunicorn-and-nginx/35433588#35433588) as not an answer when the answer was posted. Two days later he edited his complete "not-answer" so it became an answer. Now 4 days later the flag was declined.

I'm a bit annoyed that it takes 6 days for a moderator to review such a flag but that happens, nobody has unlimited time and motivation but that the flag was declined seems unreasonable to me, shouldn't it be disputed (because the author edited his question 2 days afterwards) or helpful?

Even if I had seen that he edited his "answer" I couldn't have unflagged it myself. So what's the correct way of dealing with such things in general: Don't flag it while it's fresh because someone might edit it. Wait 7 days check again and if it's still there flag it?

```
0
Communication between Gunicorn and Nginx
answered Feb 16 at 13:13 by Linc
not an answer – MSeifert Feb 16 at 13:19   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
```

Comment: An edit should invalidate a not an answer flag.  Did you custom flag it?

Comment: No, just an ordinary "Not an answer" flag, I think.

Comment: Interesting.  Any reason you did not leave a comment to the user to let them know it needs improvement?  I like to do that first and If I don't see any action then I'll flag it.

Comment: The original version was a bad answer, but still an attempt to answer. The flag was invalid from the get-go, you should have downvoted.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not sure, I can't see deleted comments but I thought someone else already did that and I upvoted it.

Comment: @Gimby [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35433588/1) reads more like a comment to me: "It needs below references to solve the error:

Ubuntu 14.04?

Have you installed django and gunicorn in virtualenv, and already tested altogether?

After deactivated env, what's the status of gunicorn service?" (see [answer])

Comment: @gnat - Thanks, that was exactly what I thought.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? An apology from the moderator that declined your flag? Guidance if you should have done something different?  Something else?

Comment: @rene - Yes, I want to know when to flag, given that the flag cannot be taken back and doesn't vanish if the post is almost completly rewritten. And a bit of help why the original post was an answer.

Comment: @MSeifert - That flag should have been cleared by the edit, since it was cast on Feb 16, and the post was edited on the 18th, with the flag being handled eight hours ago. Edits clear standard "not an answer" flags and only leave custom flags, which is generally how we can judge when something was flagged. Could you have possibly used a custom flag and filled it out with the exact words "not an answer"? That can confuse the system sometimes.

Comment: @gnat yeah true, I can follow that. Its a bit of a gray area what you can attribute as an "attempt" to answer.

Comment: @BradLarson - I'm very sure because I just opened the "flag" again at this post and it tells me "not an answer - This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. - *you have already raised this type of flag*"

Comment: @BradLarson [not all edits clear NAA](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317427/839601)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

NAA flag wasn't cleared because [post edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35433588/revisions) was made outside of review:

> ...unlike Very Low Quality flags, edits made outside of review (for instance, edits by the author of the post) don't touch Not an Answer flags.

(quote source: [Edits shouldn't dismiss “not an answer” flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252854/edits-shouldnt-dismiss-not-an-answer-flags/252860#comment871768_252854))

Comment: Thank you for the link, I like the idea about the re/de-flag-review :-)

Comment: This only explains why the NAA flag wasn't cleared but doesn't address the problem or the final questions.

Comment: @kjbartel this explains that misunderstanding between moderator and flagger in cases like this is only caused by minor and obscure system feature, this is no way a reason to change current ways

Comment: Actually it's the exact opposite. That question is about a flag being rest. This question is about a flag not being reset.

Comment: @kjbartel we seem to read it differently, then

Answer (score 61):

I'm the moderator who declined the flag -- sorry about that! Under the presumption that edits will clear the "Not An Answer" flag on a post, I usually don't check too carefully if an answer has been edited since it was NAA flagged (from the moderator queue you need to do a bit of clicking to see the edit history of a flagged post). Like Brad in the comments, I'm a bit perplexed why it remained in the moderator flag queue despite having had a major edit by the post author in this case.

Unfortunately there's no way for a moderator to "un-decline" a flag, but your flagging history seems strong regardless of the outcome on this one flag, and hopefully this won't happen too often.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and no need to apologize. I wasn't aware that NAA flags normally vanish after edits (given that it did not in this case). With that knowledge I quite understand your decision and the actual question I had is mute... Maybe the question should have been "Why did this flag persist after an edit". But I guess noone except SO-staff might answer that. Do you have any advice if this should be another question or should I report this somewhere?

Comment: @MSeifert I guess it would be best to start a new question after searching to make sure this hasn't been discussed before on meta.

Comment: @josliber [no need for a new question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317427/839601) :)

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[Try to be a good mod.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=28831066#28831066)

Comment: Obviously then the problem is that there is no indication that edits have been made since the flag was raised. This should be very obvious in the review screen. If the flag was valid when it was raised then it should be "helpful".

Comment: @MSeifert I think you do need a new question / suggestion. The linked question and comment doesn't address the problem of flags being reviewed after changes.