# NAA flag declined after answer got edited

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722378/running-python-scripts-with-argument-name-and-value/35722469#35722469) as *not an answer*, because first the OP said *"I found my error thanks for the help"*. After that he edited his answer and added a real answer, and my flag got declined. Should I use a flag for that or must I track that answer and if it didn't change should I use a flag for that?

[image: Declined flag]

Comment: I think such flags are _auto declined_ after the answer (post) was edited. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, post edited by author simply [leaves NAA flag hanging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317427/839601) until moderator or reviewers handle it