# What happens when a question or answer is updated after I raise a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

I came across an answer that was a one-line suggestion to the OP and could have been a comment. When I attempted to explain this to the poster, they disagreed, so I raised a not-an-answer flag. Some time between the raising of the flag and when a moderator had a chance to look at it, the answer was expanded into a very nice explanation, so naturally the flag was rejected.

Would the moderator have been aware of the discrepancy in the  posts we were looking at? Is there a way to reject a flag in a way that would not affect my reviewing ability at that point (i.e., can it be marked as disputed instead of declined)?

This is not a huge issue, but I can propose a couple of hypothetical solutions to it anyway:

- A flag could be disputed instead of declined by default if enough change has occurred in the post between the raising and rejection of the flag.
- A user be notified about significant edits to questions they flagged, and therefore have an opportunity to manually remove a flag if they see fit.

Comment: [Will moderators decline flags that they think should have been retracted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285632/165773)

Comment: That an answer is short doesn't mean it's supposed to be a comment.  Short answers are still answers, so it sounds like that flag would merit being declined even if the post wasn't edited.  Comments are for clarification, not for short answers.

Comment: @gnat. That does answer approximately 90% of my question.

Comment: "affect my reviewing ability"? I'm not aware of connection between flagging and reviews (unless you manually banned by mods - but I'd guess you need to have  half of flags declined to get noticed)

Comment: @Servy. I am aware of that, and I am not contesting the moderator's decision in this case, even though at the time I did think the flag was merited. I was mostly curious about how the system worked for things like that, and it appears that gnat has answered my question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. If you get enough flags declined in a short enough time, you get suspended from flagging for a little while. I think that qualifies.

Comment: I would like to close this as a dupe based on gnat's suggestion, but the answer is not on this meta. What is the correct procedure? Just deleting the question?

Comment: deletion is hardly the right thing. Even same-site duplicates aren't typically considered bad, and this is even more so for cross-site duplicates

Comment: Related: there's a feature request to [add the post revision to the moderator flag review UI](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291974).

Comment: If it's edited through the review queue, then the flag is automatically validated. Otherwise, as was the case here, nothing changes, and moderators will probably decline the flag. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317399/not-an-answer-flag-declined-because-post-was-edited-2-days-afterwards

Comment: @MadPhysicist : then you forgot the rule to edit before flagging, obviously.

Comment: @user2284570 that rule does not apply when there is no meaningful content in a post to begin with.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : but you’re talking about case it can become. So, don’t close.